Is this a latch for a double-hung window?
I have never tilted the double-hung windows open in my house. I see what looks like a latch on the bottom window and at the top of the top window. The bottom "latch" doesn't move when I press on it. The top "latch" moves when I pull out on it, but nothing seems to happen.
Anyone with similar looking latches have any ideas on how to operate it (see pictures)?

For the right side at the very top, that item at the top of the track is a sash stop. It’s there to prevent the lower sash from being raised too high.
As for the small feature on the window sash itself, I’m not convinced that it is a latch. Not all windows are designed with a feature to permit you to tilt the sash for cleaning.
It may be that if you want to remove that lower sash, you would take the sash stop off and raise it all the way. I don’t recommend doing this without further research on your part since since your window sash is likely only meant to be removed for repairs and you may encounter additional parts that help your window to raise/lower properly.
